# How to save docker state data between invocations?

Tags: docker

What do you expect would happen in the following scenario: download some database docker image, create a few tables, add a few rows and shut down the container -- is the data still there when the container is restarted again?  Intuitively, I would think that the answer is "of course" -- its so obvious, but I am not sure that its  actually the case.  I just went through a postgres image tutorial, and either I blow away the data, somehow, on startup, or the data does not stick around.  Not sure whats going on. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the data will persist in container until you explicitly or implicitly (with `docker system prune` for example) destroy it.

How does it work?

Lets say you follow classic approach and start you new container with `docker run` command, like

```
docker run ubuntu echo 'Hello' > /hello.txt
```

(`ubuntu` is just an example)

Docker pulls image `ubuntu`, creates new container (noname, but with ID) and in this container you get your file `/hello.txt`. But if you try similar command again, like

```
docker run -it ubuntu ls /
```

you wont find your file, because it is **different** container built on the same source image.

What you need is to revoke the container by using ID. Id? Seriously?? Of course, not) you can give human readable name to your container and then us it:

```
docker run --name foo ubuntu echo 'Hello' > /hello.txt
```

Now, if you want to reuse it, just call

```
docker exec foo ls /
```

This will find your container `foo` and list the root path. You will see your file. If you dont want the container to persist, use `--rm` argument with `docker run` and the container will be deleted right after exit.

So, to finalize:

1) Create named container with `docker run --name foo IMAGE`

2) Reuse them with `docker exec foo`